# How do I set two strings from one line in textfile using a devider

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out how I would set two separate strings with one line of a text file. For example,

My line in my text file says `pie:cherry`

I need to set two strings of `pie` and `cherry` and forget the `:` in the middle. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You mean get, not set, and you can do so using string.Split().

Comment: `string s = "pie:cherry"; string[] sSplit = s.Split(':'); s1 = s[0]; s2 = s[1];` `s[0]` will be "pie" and `s[1]` will be "cherry".

Comment: Use split method to split the string on ":"

Comment: Alternatively if you don't want to use [0] and [1] you could use regex with groups instead (would be more complicated than using string.split)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
string str = "pie:cherry";
string[] split = str.Split(':');

string pie = str[0];
string cherry = str[1];
```